# Open ArcGIS Business Analyst Vector Tile Service in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, vector-tiles, business-analyst

Don't even know if this is possible, but I am trying to open up a Vector Tile Service that is subscription content I have through Esri Business Analyst Online. I am able to open in ArcGIS Pro (of course), but I would like to be able to use in QGIS.

[image: Here's the data source from the layer properties in ArcGIS Pro.]

I attempted to add as:

- ArcGIS Map Service (apeared as an empty raster layer)
- ArcGIS Feature service

Adding as vector tiles does not give you the option to enter username and password as the other 2 options do.

Some more info. When I save in ArcGIS as a layer file and open it in a text editor, this is what appears:

```
{
  "type" : "CIMLayerDocument",
  "version" : "2.5.0",
  "build" : 22081,
  "layers" : [
    "CIMPATH=9062411281594e2a83fcd1acb8bc5817.xml"
  ],
  "layerDefinitions" : [
    {
      "type" : "CIMVectorTileLayer",
      "name" : "CoreLogic Parcel Point Boundaries",
      "uRI" : "CIMPATH=9062411281594e2a83fcd1acb8bc5817.xml",
      "sourceModifiedTime" : {
        "type" : "TimeInstant"
      },
      "useSourceMetadata" : true,
      "layerType" : "Operational",
      "maxScale" : 564.24858800000004,
      "minScale" : 295828763.7957775,
      "showLegends" : true,
      "visibility" : true,
      "displayCacheType" : "Permanent",
      "maxDisplayCacheAge" : 5,
      "showPopups" : true,
      "serviceLayerID" : -1,
      "refreshRate" : -1,
      "refreshRateUnit" : "esriTimeUnitsSeconds",
      "dataConnection" : {
        "type" : "CIMVectorTileDataConnection",
        "uRI" : "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/7f3041a9a89f432fbc9d536919dab1ac/resources/styles/root.json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was not support for adding Esri's proprietary vector tiles to QGIS, so I (actually my client) sponsored it's addition. It will be part of standard QGIS base functionality at 3.16.

[image: New ArcGIS vector tile service capability]